# OpenVPN UDP and TCP Traffic Fowarding

Tags: openvpn

It's been a while since I've used OpenVPN, but using the TUN configuration, how would one go about sending all TCP and UDP traffic over the VPN? Would I need two VPN Clients and Servers running? Here's my current client config:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote myvpnhost.com 8080   

resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun

ca "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\laptop.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\laptop.key"
ns-cert-type server

comp-lzo
verb 3
#explicit-exit-notify 2
#ping 10
#ping-restart 60

route-method exe
route-delay 2

#last updated June 04, 2011
```

Comment: I don't understand your issue, UDP traffic is actually sent encapsulated through your OpenVPN tunnel using TCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:  `proto tcp` means that your client will communicate with your OpenVPN server through TCP.

Your traffic (UDP & TCP) is already going through your OpenVPN TCP-based tunnel.

Comment: This answers my question, I guess I phrased it poorly. I wasn't sure if I needed a separate OpenVPN server for the UDP traffic.